# Login PHP e MySql gerando erro mysqli_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia!

Tenho o seguinte código para fazer login no sistema:

```
<?php


require_once('conexao.php');

// FETCH DATA FROM FORM USING METHOD POST
// IF BUTTON NAME "LOGIN" IS SET
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {




// FETCH DATA FROM INPUT FIELD
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['password']);

  // CHECK ALL FIELD HAS BEEN FILLED UP
 if ($user && $pass) {

   // QUERY FROM DATABASE
  $query= mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='".$user."'");
  $checkuser= mysqli_num_rows($query);

   // CHECK IF USERNAME EXIST ON DATABASE
  if($checkuser != 1) {

    // I'LL BE SETTING A VARIABLE IF YOUR DOESN'T EXIST
   $error = "Username doesn't exist in our database!";
  }

   // FETCHING PASSWORD IN DATABASE WHERE USERNAME COINCIDES
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user)) {
   $checkpass= $row['senha'];


    // CHECK IF ENTERED PASSWORD MEETS THE USERNAME PASSWORD
   if ($pass== $checkpass) {

     // IF ALL OKAY SET SESSION
    setcookie("usuario", $user, time()+7200);
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60 * 60 * 60);
    header("Location: ../admin.php");
    exit();
   } else {

     // SET VARIABLE THAT'LL SHOW IF USER PASSWORD IS INCORRECT
    $error = "Incorrect password!";
   }
  }
 } else {

  // SET VARIABLE IF ALL FIELD ARE NOT FILLED UP
 $error = "Please enter a username and password.";
 }
}


?>
```

Ao tentar logar-se, na página de "login.php", recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetoqa\php\checklogin.php on line 32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
```

O primeiro parâmetro de [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) deve ser um `resulttype`e não uma *string*, que é a variável `$user`.

Na sua lógica, coloque tudo que vem depois da checagem do usuário dentro de um `else`:

```
if($checkuser != 1) {
    // I'LL BE SETTING A VARIABLE IF YOUR DOESN'T EXIST
    $error = "Username doesn't exist in our database!";
}
else {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        ....
```

Se não esse código será executado quando o usuário não for encontrado e poderá resultar em erro. E como sua query deve retornar apenas um registro, o `while` não é necessário.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado pela ajuda! Deu certinho! Outra duvida, não sei se pode ser sanada por aqui mesmo. No meu sistema, caso o usuário troque a url para o lugar que loga, no caso "admin.php", ele consegue acessar sem logar-se. Certo? É algo relacionado com este código aqui? Ou algum outro procedimento?

Comment: @RodrigoBRF nesse caso o correto seria você criar um arquivo onde você checa pela sessão que você criou no processo de login. Se ela estive *vencida* você dá acesso negado. Esse arquivo você tem que incluir em toda página com acesso restrito, no início. Eu geralmente salvo - nesse mesmo arquivo - o horário que o usuário acessou, mas antes checo se já faz mais de 5 minutos - ou o tempo que preferir - que foi acessado, então a sessão é invalidada.

Comment: perfeito! pesquisarei mais à fundo à respeito depois que terminar o resto da programação. obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa passar $query para mysqli_fetch_array ao invés de passar a varíavel $user.

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Funcionou com sua dica!